# Show using rolle's theorem that the equation $\tan x=x$ has an infinity of solutions

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Given the function $f$ defined as :

1. for every $x \in ]0,1]$ : $f(x)=x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$
2. $f(0)=0$

Show using rolle's theorem on the function $f$ in a specific interval that the equation $\tan x=x$ has an infinity of solutions

I tried to apply Rolle's in $]0,1]$ but i didn't find the good result i get that exists c in $]0,1[$ such that

$tan(\frac{\pi}{c})=\frac{\pi}{c}$

Comment: Try using Rolle's theorem on $[1/(n+1),1/n]$.

Comment: Can you give me another hint

Comment: What does Rolle's theorem say with that $f$ and the interval $[1/(n+1=,1/n]$?